# Unable to launch the chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Can anyone please tell me the solution for the below-mentioned error?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
#chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
print ("chrome driver launched successfully...")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_selenium/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test_selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test_selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test_selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service F:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error from time to time. Something that worked for me was downloading another version of selenium web driver (Upgrading always worked for me but if it doesn't work for you try downgrading as well)